# Internal server error when changing to https

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

My Yii site is giving an internal server error 500 after changing http to https in .htaccess when entering this line of code:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

I have a valid SSL because my WordPress sites are working fine with https.

Also my site is a subdomain, but I don't think that would be the problem.

What can it be?

Comment: "internal server error" is very generic and says almost nothing. You should look into logs to get more info about source of this error.

Comment: All right, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Fixed it! Found the issue in the errorlog. Had to insert rewritebase / in the .htaccess file. Thank you once again!

Comment: Add this as answer and accept it - it may be useful for someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errorlog: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

Fixed issue: Had to insert "rewritebase /" in the .htaccess file.